# Adzerk ads loaded insecurely on some SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, ssl

While answering [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219926/google-shield-on-so-insecure-content), I noticed that I get the following warnings about blocked insecure active content while viewing math.SE over HTTPS:

> [image: Screenshot]

The first warning, about MathJax, is [a known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/ssl-breaks-tex-rendering).  The second one, however, appears to be unrelated to it, and I can also reproduce it on other SE sites, such as [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com), that don't use MathJax.

Curiously, however, it *doesn't* happen on SO.  Looking at the page source, it appears that it has already been fixed on SO, where the script that loads the ads looks like this (uncompressed for readability):

```javascript
<script>
    var p = "http", d = "static";
    if (document.location.protocol == "https:") {
        p += "s"; d = "engine";
    }
    var z = document.createElement("script");
    z.type = "text/javascript";
    z.async = true;
    z.src = p + "://" + d + ".adzerk.net/ados.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);
</script>
```

On math.SE and Arqade, however, the corresponding script simply looks like this:

```javascript
<script>
    var z = document.createElement("script");
    z.async = true;
    z.src = 'http://engine.adzerk.net/z/12057/adzerk2_2_17_76?keywords=x-host-gaming.stackexchange.com';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);
</script>
```

I suppose the fix already in place on SO just needs to be ported to the other SE network sites as well.

---

**Addendum:** Also noticed that SE Careers 2.0 ads on SO sometimes get blocked as insecure content too.  (This is really a separate issue, but I'm too lazy to post another bug report.)

The offending code seems to be this (again, uncompressed):

```javascript
<script>
    window.careers_adurl = "http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/companyjs",
    window.careers_cssurl = "//cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/company.min.css?v=4ed6f5dfc932",
    window.careers_cssurl2 = "//cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/sidebar.min.css?v=ed74a1a226c6",
    window.careers_adselector = "#hireme",
    StackExchange.ready( function () {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "//cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/company-loader.min.js?v=d38fcbba30f7",
            dataType: "script", 
            cache: !1
        } )
    } );
</script>
```

Notice how, out of the four URLs in the script, three are protocol-relative but one is not.  Since they all do seem to work over HTTPS, simply removing the `http:` from the code should fix this one.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into it. Repro'd for arqade et al. Would you happen to remember where on SO you were when you saw the careers error? I see slightly different, protocol relative code when inspecting the careers ad.

Comment: Careers ads should be good now.